# Accessing TFS API from machines without Team Explorer

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs-sdk

Can I use TFS API in my code and deploy the code in the machine where Visual Studio or Team Explorer doesn't exist?

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/a1f63cf9-b57d-4b58-ba8f-5e2747e3c614), which says I shouldn't do that.

Any help on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [new OData API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/10/26/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-2010-v1.aspx), or the [standard WebService API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5232780/736079) ([officially unsupported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsstart/thread/a388cdc5-2933-4b27-bc7f-ae5ac2bd695f/)) to connect to TFS without the need for the SDK or Team Explorer on the machine.

And there's the [Java API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-a-java-sdk-for-tfs.aspx)'s that ship with [Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25125), which are supposedly easier to use in stand-alone fashion than the .NET API's that require Team Explorer to be installed.

Do note that in order to follow the proper license terms, you generally do need to have a [TFS CAL for every machine/user connecting to TFS](http://www.sanderstechnology.com/2011/visual-studio-2010-and-msdn-licensing-white-paper/10710/#.T32P16vVyAg).

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, when you develop client application for the TFS, this means you need the run time files for this API which is exists in the Team Explorer.