# Accessing Information of the Team Foundation Server via Web Services

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to Access Information of Builds of Team Projects to use them in other Applications of our Company.
What I need is requesting all Builds for a Team Projekt.
I need Information like:
- the UNC Path the Outlut was copied to
- the Name
- Date of Build
- who started ór triggered the Build (if possible)

I did not find any discription how the Access Information on TFS via Web Services. What I learned is that TFS has a Service Interface.

I hope anyone can give me a litte hint how to reach my goal. If anyone has some sample code I surely would be delighted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like that be helpful:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace BuildDetails
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsURI"));
            var buildService = (IBuildServer)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

            IBuildDefinition buildDefinition = buildService.GetBuildDefinition("TeamProjectName", "BuildDefinitionName");
            IBuildDetail[] buildDetails = buildService.QueryBuilds(buildDefinition);

            foreach (var buildDetail in buildDetails)
            {
                IBuildInformation buildInformation = buildDetail.Information;
                Console.Write(buildDetail.BuildNumber+"\t");
                Console.Write(buildDefinition.Name+"\t");
                Console.Write(buildDetail.Status+"\t");
                Console.Write(buildDetail.StartTime+"\t");
                Console.WriteLine((buildDetail.FinishTime - buildDetail.StartTime).Minutes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a standard usage of the TFS-SDK, and I think it provides with the info you 're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this great exaple. I do not get it running because I allways get an "HTTP 404 Page not Found" Error back.

my Calls looks like that:
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://MyTfsServerHostName:8080/tfs"));

This is the URL I configures Visual Studio with... I also tried http://MyTfsServerHostName as well with an Error 501

Comment: In Team Explorer, right-click on the master-node of the Team Collection and select Properties. Use what you see in the `Url` property (something like `http://TFSName:8080/tfs/CollectionName`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [wrapper for the wrapper](http://tfsapiwrapper.codeplex.com/) to access to TFS since it's much easier and may be enough for what you need.

If not, I suggest using [TFS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you still want to go lower, then please read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227376/is-there-any-documentation-on-tfs-web-services).